# Why do some CMake examples use triple quotes for keywords?

Tags: cmake

For example, the way OBJECT and the TARGET_OBJECT expressions are triple quoted in the Usage section [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library).

Comment: Smells like a formatting issue.  On my system cmake tries to find a source file named `'''OBJECT'''`.

Comment: Most of their docs were moved from one system to another so most likely what you are seeing are the artifacts of that process.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought maybe it was some new way of making sure keywords were not confused with variables or expressions.